# Use scientific notation in log spreadsheet labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a chart with a normal X axis, but a logarithmic Y axis. The range for the Y axis is between about 10<sup>−19</sup> to 1. After adjusting the Y axis label to show each power of ten, the Y axis label column looks like this:

```
           1
         0.1
        0.01
       0.001
      0.0001
     0.00001
    0.000001
   0.0000001
  0.00000001
 0.000000001
0.0000000001
           0
           0
           0
           0
           0
           0
           0
           0
```

I would prefer that it display the labels in scientific notation (below, "good"), or better yet, plain decimal down until the number of leading zeros gets unwieldy, then scientific notation (below "better").

```
  good    better
 1 E+0    1
 1 E-1    0.1
 1 E-2    0.01
 1 E-3    0.001
 1 E-4    0.0001
 1 E-5    1 E-5
 1 E-6    1 E-6
 1 E-7    1 E-7
 1 E-8    1 E-8
 1 E-9    1 E-9
 1 E-10   1 E-10
 1 E-11   1 E-11
 1 E-12   1 E-12
 1 E-13   1 E-13
 1 E-14   1 E-14
 1 E-15   1 E-15
 1 E-16   1 E-16
 1 E-17   1 E-17
 1 E-18   1 E-18
 1 E-19   1 E-19
```

Is there any way to do this in Google Spreadsheets?

And in case I can't do it in Google Spreadsheets, would I be able to do it in Excel instead?

Comment: In Excel, you can apply the desired number format to the axis labels

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , thanks. If I can't find a fix in Google Spreadsheet, it's good to know that I can import to Excel as a solution.